# Add only new rows to existing csv using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

Ok I don't know how to program this correctly. Have tried many combinations and I have reached a dead end since logic is wrong. I have managed to fetch data from the web and placed this data inside a csv file using pandas. The script will be run every 15 min to fetch data.

In this case down below I have created a dummy called "data".
Data will be sometimes different if new updates are available and sometimes it will look the same depending on changes made by the provider.

However if I run the script again, it will only populate the csv file with same data. This I dont want but I only want to add rows, append if there is new unique data.

As an example

```
import os
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import html5lib
import csv

data = [('Peter', 18, 7), ('Dick',22,2),
                        ('Riff', 15, 6), 
                        ('John', 17, 8), 
                        ('Michel', 18, 7), 
                        ('Sheli', 17, 5) ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# if file exists....
if os.path.isfile('filename.csv'):
    #Old data
    oldFrame = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
    
    #Concat
    df_diff = pd.concat([oldFrame, df],ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

    #Write new rows to csv file
    df_diff.to_csv('filename.csv', mode='a', header=False)
    
else: # else it exists so append
    df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

However this does not work and gives me wrong data so logic is wrong. What to do to achive what I want? Is there any better method to use?

#### UPDATE

Have changed script like this by help from good fellows...

```
import os
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import html5lib
import csv

data = [('Adam', 18, 7), ('Magnus',22,2),('Lena',22,2),('Gringo', 18, 7)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
##
### if file exists....
if os.path.isfile('filename.csv'):
    #Old data
    oldFrame = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', header=None)
    
    #Concat
    df_diff = pd.concat([oldFrame, df], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()

    #Write new rows to csv file
    df_diff.to_csv('filename.csv', header=False)
    
else:

    # else it exists so append
    df.to_csv('filename.csv')
    print("File Created...")
```

Have run the script many times with same "data" values....
However output of dataframe looks like this (if calling oldFrame)

```
>>> oldFrame
     0       1       2       3       4     5    6
0    0       0       0     NaN       0   1.0  2.0
1    1       1       1     0.0    Adam  18.0  7.0
2    2       2       2     1.0  Magnus  22.0  2.0
3    3       3       3     2.0    Lena  22.0  2.0
4    4       4       4     3.0  Gringo  18.0  7.0
5    5       5       5    Adam      18   7.0  NaN
6    6       6       6  Magnus      22   2.0  NaN
7    7       7       7    Lena      22   2.0  NaN
8    8       8       8  Gringo      18   7.0  NaN
9    9       9    Adam      18       7   NaN  NaN
10  10      10  Magnus      22       2   NaN  NaN
11  11      11    Lena      22       2   NaN  NaN
12  12      12  Gringo      18       7   NaN  NaN
13  13    Adam      18       7     NaN   NaN  NaN
14  14  Magnus      22       2     NaN   NaN  NaN
15  15    Lena      22       2     NaN   NaN  NaN
16  16  Gringo      18       7     NaN   NaN  NaN
```

Shouldn't the csv not be changed since the data is same?

Comment: why do you need to append to the csv if you already concat the old data to the new? the old data will appear twice

Comment: Trigonom - You have a point there. But how to compare new data with old then?

Answer (score 1):

When you read the existing file, it takes the first row as header.

Since you are not using the header, specify **not to read it**.

replace

```
oldFrame = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

by

```
oldFrame = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', header=None)
```

Also, **remove the** `keep=False` in `drop_duplicates`

```
df_diff = pd.concat([oldFrame, df],ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()
```

and the `mode='a'` when `to_csv`

```
df_diff.to_csv('filename.csv', header=False)
```

### UPDATE

note I edit both `to_csv` calls

final script

```
import os
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import csv

data = [('Peter', 18, 7), ('Dick',22,2),
                        ('Riff', 15, 6), 
                        ('John', 17, 8), 
                        ('Michel', 18, 7), 
                        ('NEW', 2, 5), 
                        ('other', 2, 5), 
                        ('Sheli', 17, 5) ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# if file exists....
if os.path.isfile('filename.csv'):
    #Old data
    oldFrame = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', header=None)

    #Concat
    df_diff = pd.concat([oldFrame, df],ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()

    #Write new rows to csv file
    df_diff.to_csv('filename.csv', header=False, index=False)

else: # else it exists so append
    df.to_csv('filename.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks friend for reaching out. Have changed the script to your changes but I get oddities as shown in above post.

Comment: I recorded the steps. The script is working for me.
Look at this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hhY7hXA9Q6u1jSQJHNFVWjYLTxrf_sLI/view