# How to prevent pandas.dataframe.to_csv from creating new columns when appending?

Tags: python, pandas

I am following [Freddy's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60327411/add-only-new-rows-to-existing-csv-using-pandas) example in appending my csv file with unique values. Here is the code I am using:

```
header = ['user.username', 'user.id']
user_filename = f"{something}_users.csv"

if os.path.isfile(user_filename): #checks if file exists
    #Read in old data
    oldFrame = pd.read_csv(user_filename, header=0)

    #Concat and drop dups
    df_diff = pd.concat([oldFrame, df[['user.username', 'user.id']]],ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()

    #Write new rows to csv file
    df_diff.to_csv(user_filename, header = False, index=False)

else: # else it exists so append
    df.to_csv(user_filename, columns = header, header=['username', 'user_id'], index=False, mode = 'a')
```

Running this code for the first time returns the desired result: A csv file with two named columns (username and user_id) and the respective values. If I run it a second time, something odd happens: I still keep the old values and also the new values. But the new values appear below the old ones in two new (unnamed) columns like so:

```
username    user_id
user1       123
user2       456
                     user3     789
                     user4     124
```

The output I'm looking for is this:

```
username    user_id
user1       123
user2       456
user3       789
user4       124
```

Comment: How to guess without more info, but I would assume that the headers have fields with different names, so the `pd .concat` operation creates different columns.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with the code is of naming convention. Try this piece of code

```
header = ['user.username', 'user.user_id']
user_filename = "users.csv"

if os.path.isfile(user_filename): #checks if file exists
    #Read in old data
    oldFrame = pd.read_csv(user_filename, header=0)
    
    #Concat and drop dups
    concat = pd.concat([oldFrame, df[['user.username', 'user.user_id']]], ignore_index=True)
    df_diff = concat.drop_duplicates()
    
    
    #Write new rows to csv file
    df_diff.to_csv(user_filename, header=['user.username', 'user.user_id'], index=False)

else: # else it exists so append
    df.to_csv(user_filename, columns = header, header=['user.username', 'user.user_id'], index=False, mode='a')
```

What this code does differently is, that the name of the headers you are reading from the file should be the same as the names of headers you are trying to concatenate the data with. You can use some interim dictionary to achieve this if you don't want to change your column names.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by concatenating two dataframes with different column names. The imported dataframe already has the new column names (`'username'` and `'user_id'`), the dataframe `df` still uses `'user.username'` and `'user.id'`.

To avoid the error, I changed this line

```
df_diff = pd.concat([oldFrame, df[['user.username', 'user.id']]],ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()
```

to

```
df_diff = pd.concat([oldFrame, df[['user.username', 'user.id']].rename(columns={"user.username": "username", "user.id": "user_id"})],ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()
```